# How to add subject in custom email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have created custom email template in magento2. Mail function is working fine, but subject is not sent in that email. How can I add the subject in my custom email template.

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
       ->setTemplateIdentifier('my_custom_email_template')
       ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ]
        )
       ->setTemplateVars($vars)
       ->setFrom($sender)
       ->addTo($toEmail)
       ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can write email subject to in your email .html file

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Your Subject Write Here "}}  @-->
```

You can pass subject dynamic by follow below example

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Welcome to %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
```

Comment: It's working fine thanks.I have another doubt in case if it dynamic means how can we pass to email.html file

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @SureshChikani i would like to add in the controller how to do?

Comment: Thank you for good answer. it working till today, i hope this solution work in future @SureshChikani

Answer (score 1):

please make ensure you added the below line in your email template file.

```
<!--@subject Subject Of your email  @-->
```

More reference follow the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123779/how-to-add-subject-in-tranctional-email-template-for-magento-2-version

Answer (score 1):

> Use the method clearSubject(), but to apply when you are to call getMessage() method, let this example over here

```
$transport = $this
    ->transportBuilder
    ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template')
    ->setTemplateOptions( [
        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
    ])
    ->setTemplateVars(array())
    ->setFrom($sender)
    ->addTo($toEmail, '')
    >getTransport();
$transport
    ->getMessage()
    ->setMessageType( \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface::TYPE_HTML)
    ->setBody($MyHtml)
    ->clearSubject()
    ->setSubject("MySubject");
$transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: i got error on m2 as Error: Call to undefined method Vianetz\AdvancedInvoiceLayout\Model\Mail\Template\MultiPartTransportBuilder\Interceptor::clearSubject() in

Answer (score 1):

I tried and It was working

For multiple replacements, try this

`<!--@subject {{trans "%candidate_name applied to %job_name" candidate_name=$candidate.full_name job_name=$job_name}} @-->`

Comment: its working for me <!--@subject {{trans "Kaffee Widerrufsbelehrung"}} @-->

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the file *vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\email\submitted_form.html* to your Theme at **THEME\Magento_Contact\email\submitted_form.html**

then change the title like this:

### Before

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Contact Form"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.comment":"Comment",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Phone"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

### After

Example: Changes subject to "Welcome at %name_of_your_shop%"

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Welcome to %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.comment":"Comment",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Phone"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

### What can you use?

There is a method which contains all data which you can use, search the method `addEmailVariables()` in the file **vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php**

For example the store object is set here like this:

```
protected function addEmailVariables($variables, $storeId)
{
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    if (!isset($variables['store'])) {
        $variables['store'] = $store;
    }
    ...
```

If this is not enough, then you have to extend this method from your module.